# How to pass this value in c# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable to an object.
I want to pass the value of `cod` passed to `MisArticulos.codigo`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AgregarArticulos(ArticuloModel articulo)
{
        ArticulosSele MisArticulos = new ArticulosSele();
        List<ArticulosSele> ListaArticulosFactura = new 
        List<ArticulosSele>();
        dbModels dbArtFact = new dbModels();
        ListaArticulosFactura = dbArtFact.ArticulosSele.ToList();

        var Seleccionados = articulo.Articulos.Where(x => x.IsChecked == 
            true).ToList<Articulos>();
        int tamaño = Seleccionados.Count();//Obtenemos el tamaño de la lista
        for (int i= 0;  i< tamaño; i++) {
            //MisArticulos.foliofactura = idfact;
            int cod= (int)Seleccionados[i].codigo;
            //"MisArticulos.codigo" gives me 0, but "cod" has a value.
            MisArticulos.codigo = cod; 
            MisArticulos.nombre = Seleccionados[i].nombre;//the same problem here
        }
}
```

Comment: A hint from a native speaker: while understandable, the word "Im" is not correct; it should be "I'm" (with an apostrophe) since it's actually two words, "I am" combined into one, like "I'll". I've fixed it, just wanted to help :).

Comment: This code isn't really a minimal example, as in I cannot copy paste it and have it work the same way as it is doing on your end.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your suggestion I will try to correct it.

Comment: @Neijwiert I'm sorry, I'm just learning, I'll correct the question. thanks for your feedback.:)

Comment: ArticulosSele MisArticulos = new ArticulosSele(); You define MisArticulos with an uppercase, please try using the standard c# naming conventions. This will make it easier to read. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in your for loop. `MisArticulos` is a single object, so `MisArticulos.codigo = cod;` is repeatedly writing over the previous value until the end of the for loop, where presumably `cod` is 0.

You probably meant to have a list instead, like

`List<ArticulosSele> MisArticulos = new List<ArticulosSele>();`

and then fill it in your for loop, like

```
for (int i = 0;  i < tamaño; i++) {
    MisArticulos[i].codigo = Seleccionados[i].codigo;    
    MisArticulos[i].nombre = Seleccionados[i].nombre;
}
```